# OOP PHP - get_object_vars

Tags: php, oop

I saw how get_object_vars works at php.net.

The thing is that I can't make it work in my OOP script.

There's user.php file that extends DatabaseObject:

```
<?php 
require_once('database.php');

class User extends DatabaseObject {

    protected static $tableName = 'users';
    protected static $tableID = 'id';

    public $id;
    public $username;   
    public $password;   
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;



}

?>
```

and here's databaseobject.php itself:

```
<?php 
require_once('database.php');

class DatabaseObject {


    public static function findAll(){
        global $database;
        $calledClass = get_called_class();      
        return self::findBySQL("SELECT * FROM ".static::$tableName."");
    }

    public static function findByID($id){
        global $database;
        $calledClass = get_called_class();      
        $result_array = self::findBySQL("SELECT * FROM ".static::$tableName." WHERE ".static::$tableID." = {$id}");
        return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
    }

    public static function findBySQL($sql){
        global $database;
        $result_set = $database->query($sql);
        $object_array = array();
        while ($row = $database->fetchArray($result_set)) {
          $object_array[] = self::instantiate($row);
        }
        return $object_array;       
    }

    private static function instantiate($record){
        $calledClass = get_called_class();      
        $object = new $calledClass;
        foreach($record as $attribute=>$value){
          if($object->has_attribute($attribute)) {
            $object->$attribute = $value;
          }
        }
        return $object;
    }

    private function has_attribute($attribute) {
      $object_vars = $this->attributes();
      return array_key_exists($attribute, $object_vars);
    }

    public function attributes(){
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }

    protected function cleanAttributes(){
        global $database;
        $cleanAttributes = array();
        foreach($this->attributes() as $key => $value) {
            $cleanAttributes[$key] = $database->escapeValue($value);
        }
        return $cleanAttributes;
    }   

    public function save() {
        return(isset($this->id)) ? $this->update() : $this->create();   
    }

    protected function create() {
        global $database;
        //$calledClass = get_called_class();
        //$class = new $calledClass;
        $attributes = $this->cleanAttributes();     
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".static::$tableName." (";
        $sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
        $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
        $sql .= join("', '", array_keys($attributes));
        $sql .= "')";   
        if($database->query($sql)) {
            $this->id = $database->insert_id();
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The create() function should take the values stored inside the public vars in users.php and store them in DB. now as the values of my vars I'm getting the attributes themselves as for $username I have value 'username'.

Where am I wrong? I'm newbie to OOP PHP... :P

Comment: @xdazz with your help today I managed to solve my problem and understand where I was wrong.. maybe this time you can save me too...

Comment: Looks like terrible design, as your other post. Please don't create duplicates, and learn about static and instance variables.

Comment: Terrible question title, too.

Comment: Thanks, your replys are so optimistic.. I'm asking questions because I don't know HOW, and that's why I want to hear the ideas from the community...

Comment: @Mikey: What others are trying to tell is that the answer is: "don't ask HOW to do this, because you SHOULD NOT be doing it like this in the first place". If you are studying OOP, just forget about get_object_vars - if you need it, it means you are using objects as arrays anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your query:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".static::$tableName." (";
    $sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
    $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
    $sql .= join("', '", array_keys($attributes));
    $sql .= "')";
```

Note that you are using `array_keys()` as both your field names **and** your values.  You should use `array_values()` for your values instead.